# ionic 3 Close ion-item-sliding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a sliding item that when you swipe it open, it reveals a submit button.

[image]

[image]

After you hit submit, I would like for the button to close and hide the "submit". I can't seem to find any documentation for closing sliding elements that relate to buttons or any hacks around it. Any suggestions? Working in Ionic 3...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like you can see **[in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/#close)**:

> Close the sliding item. Items can also be closed from the List.
>
> The sliding item can be closed by grabbing a reference to
>   `ItemSliding`. In the below example, the template reference variable
>   `slidingItem` is placed on the element and passed to the `share`
>   method.
>
> ```
> <ion-list>
>   <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem>
>     <ion-item>
>       Item
>     </ion-item>
>     <ion-item-options>
>       <button ion-button (click)="share(slidingItem)">Share</button>
>     </ion-item-options>
>   </ion-item-sliding>
> </ion-list>
> ```

And then:

> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { ItemSliding } from 'ionic-angular';
>
> @Component({...})
> export class MyClass {
>   constructor() { }
>
>   share(slidingItem: ItemSliding) {
>     slidingItem.close();
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: required using ion-item-sliding when using ion-item tag beside it

Answer (score 4):

From the [Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/#close):

Html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem>
    <ion-item>
      Item
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options>
      <button ion-button (click)="share(slidingItem)">Share</button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemSliding } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyClass {
  constructor() { }

  share(slidingItem: ItemSliding) {
    slidingItem.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the other answers are totaly correct but we don't need to pass a refrence of component just tp call close method , I usually try to do something like this logic if possible on the template,and here is a prefect example where we just want to call a method related to component.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem>
    <ion-item>
      Item
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options>
     <button ion-button (click)="share();slidingItem.close()">Share</button>
     <button ion-button routerLink="/" (click)="slidingItem.close()"> Det</button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

> with event binding we can call more than method if we separate them with **`;`** like this `(click)="share();slidingItem.close()"`

Comment: Are you tested this and you are able to get to close the slideItem from the html template without involving TS code?  I am getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined``` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 5+ / Angular 12+**

This works for me: i.e. I need to close all the opened sliding items when the page leaves.

*.html*

```
<ion-list #slidingList>  
  //sliding code
</ion-list>
```

*.ts*

```
 @ViewChild('slidingList') slidingList: IonList;

  constructor() {}

 ionViewDidLeave(): void {
   this.slidingList.closeSlidingItems();
  }
```